# Bug in cs50x 2022 cash.c

Tags: c, cs50

My code works out perfectly, it compiles perfectly on my computer, but it doesn't work when I check50 it, it gives the correct result, and it seems well optimized. When I use the check50 command, it says:

```
:) cash.c exists
:( cash.c compiles
    code failed to compile
:| get_cents returns integer number of cents
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| get_cents rejects negative input
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| get_cents rejects a non-numeric input of "foo" 
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| calculate_quarters returns 2 when input is 50
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| calculate_quarters returns 1 when input is 42
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| calculate_dimes returns 1 when input is 10
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| calculate_dimes returns 1 when input is 15
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| calculate_dimes returns 7 when input is 73
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| calculate_nickels returns 1 when input is 5
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| calculate_nickels returns 5 when input is 28
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| calculate_pennies returns 4 when input is 4
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| input of 41 cents yields output of 4 coins
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| input of 160 cents yields output of 7 coins
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
```

And here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int greedy_calculation(int greedyInput);

int main(void)
{
    int changeOwed = 0;
    do
    {
        changeOwed = get_int("Changed owed: ");
    }
    while(changeOwed < 1);

    changeOwed = greedy_calculation(changeOwed);

    printf("%i\n", changeOwed);
}

int greedy_calculation(int greedyInput)
{
    int finalResult = 0;

    do
    {
        while((greedyInput - 25) >= 0)
        {
            greedyInput -= 25;
            finalResult++;
        }

        while((greedyInput - 10) >= 0)
        {
            greedyInput -= 10;
            finalResult++;
        }

        while((greedyInput - 5) >= 0)
        {
            greedyInput -= 5;
            finalResult++;
        }

        while((greedyInput - 1) >= 0)
        {
            greedyInput -= 1;
            finalResult++;
        }
    }
    while(greedyInput != 0);

    return finalResult;
}
```

I am well aware that I still need to add comments, but I'm more stuck with as to why it doesn't work, thanks so much for your help :D

Comment: I think it compiles fine *locally*, but then they have to upload it to a course website? I don't know cs50, so I'm filling in the blanks here. @WhozCraig

Comment: Ignoring the CS-50 header, it does compile cleanly. So the problem doesn't seem to be in the code posted.

Comment: @Lundin Any suspicion as to what is could be then?

Comment: Did you upload the code you intended?

Comment: What exact command are you using to run `check50`?

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry, I fixed it :D

Comment: What command are you using to compile locally, and how do you know that actually successfully compiles?

Comment: Does the code on the git branch you're checking match the actual local code that successfully compiles?

Comment: @JohnFilleau to compile it i just use the normal "make cash", and to run it i just use "./cash". And how do i go about checking if it matches the git branch? And the exact check50 code i use is "check50 cs50/problems/2022/x/cash"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [spec](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/1/cash/) (emphasis added):

> CS50x 2022’s version of Cash is quite different than CS50x 2021’s version. It will be in your best interest to do this problem from scratch, if you do not have credit for the work you did in 2021. Last year’s version will fail to compile when checked by check50 due to the fact that in this new version, **you must implement functions which the testing suite will test independently,** beyond just checking for the final answer (as last year’s versiondid).

check50 expects that you start with the supplied (2022) distro code and follow the spec instructions.

Comment: @DinoCodeSaurus Apologies for my incompetence, but what does that essentially mean, do i need to add functions for all the change calculations? The reason I didn't initially do that is because it seems insufficient declaring a function that has just a few lines of code in it, whereas just making one function, and putting all the calculations in that, seems much better. But I don't really know, it's just my two cents. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: One of the "lessons" of this class is adhering to the spec. The only thing at stake is a grade, which may or may not be important to you. If a specification from a boss or a client is not followed, the consequences may translate to real money.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you, I'll fix it then :D